# How do I start / initialize a .Net Core minimal API in a separate test project (for pact tests)?

Tags: asp.net-core, .net-core, asp.net-core-webapi, pact

I am working on a Pact-Net ([Pact.io](http://pact.io)) proof of concept using .Net Core 7. I have the consumer side working correctly both making calls and generating the pact file. My issue is the .Net core 7 provider (API) side. I have created a standalone minimal API and it works correctly when I start it by itself.

However, the issue is that I need to be able to initialize the API as part of a separate test project so that the tests can run the pact file against the API.

My API code looks like this...

```
public static void Main(string[] args)
{
    ProviderStartup.Start();
}

public static class ProviderStartup
{
    public static void Start()
    {
        var repository = ProductRepository.GetInstance();

        var builder = WebApplication.CreateBuilder();
        var webApp = builder.Build();

        webApp.MapGet("/products", () => repository.GetProducts());
        webApp.MapGet("/product/{id}", (string id) => repository.GetProduct(id));

        webApp.Run();
    }
}
```

However, all of the examples for how to start the api from the test project look similar to what is below and I cannot make it work...

```
private string _providerUri { get; }
private string _pactServiceUri { get; }
private IWebHost _webHost { get; }
private ITestOutputHelper _outputHelper { get; }

public ProviderApiTests(ITestOutputHelper output)
{
    _outputHelper = output;
    _providerUri = "http://localhost:7008";
    _pactServiceUri = "http://localhost:9001";

    _webHost = WebHost.CreateDefaultBuilder()
        .UseUrls(_pactServiceUri)
        .UseStartup<Startup>()
        .Build();

    _webHost.Start();
}
```

Does anyone know how to start up an API project from within a test project so that it can be consumed by the Pact contract tests?

Answer (score 0):

It doesn't appear to work very well to use TestServer or any of the application builders. However, starting the API using Process works really well.

```
// Test constructor
public ProviderApiTests(ITestOutputHelper output)
{
    _outputHelper = output;
    _providerUri = "http://localhost:5000";

    var startInfo = new ProcessStartInfo();
    startInfo.FileName = "Provider.exe";
    _process = Process.Start(startInfo);
}
```

NOTE: In your TearDown or Dispose, make sure you add a Process.Kill() call to stop the API.